# Bypass AP Isolate for some devices

Tags: wireless-access-point, hostapd

I have some devices connected to a wireless AP running from hostapd that has AP isolation on. With this, none of the devices can ping each other. However, I would like 2 or more of those devices to be able to ping each other across the WAP. I've done some research but can't seem to find any solution that works for me. Is there a way I can set up a static route or bridge between say 192.168.0.5 and 192.168.0.7 so that they can ping each other over wlan?

Comment: Disabling AP isolation is not an option?

Comment: Disable AP isolation, enslave the AP to a bridge, and filter with a nft bridge family table, I suppose. (But since all the clients share the same bridge port, you can at best filter with MAC address and/or IP address, which means the approach would be vulnerable to MAC spoofing.)

Comment: Would it be an option to simply setup a second WiFi network without isolation? Basically like in a classic home+guest network configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow them to talk through the router/gateway.

1. If the router is running Linux, enable the "proxy_arp_pvlan" option, so that it'll 'proxy'-answer ARP requests on behalf on hosts on the *same* subnet. (This will cause problems if the same subnet is shared with an un-isolated ethernet; it should only be done when the AP has a dedicated subnet.)
2. Now whenever hosts talk to 192.168.0.7, they'll send all packets to the router's MAC address (due to the proxy-ARP response), and the router will forward the packets back onto the subnet – where the *real* 192.168.0.7 will receive them (almost as if you didn't have AP isolation).
3. Finally, use *firewall rules* (the 'FORWARD' chain) on the router to control which hosts are allowed to talk to what. In your case, have two rules allowing .5 and .7 to talk to each other, while blocking everything else.